# Laravel date not allowing me to use diffForHumans

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

have my table set up with a timestamp fields for created and updated at fields.

In my model I then do this:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

But when calling the date:

```
$p->created_at->diffForHumans()
```

I get

```
Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string
```

I'm pretty sure that should work. I have used the same many times before on different models etc but this just won't work.

Comment: You actually don't need to list the `created_at` and `updated_at` in the `$dates` property. Laravel already takes care of that for you behind the scenes. Anyway, are you possibly mutating or casting the attribute?

Comment: Or getting the record with a non-eloquent-model query? DB::statement might not cast those values.

Comment: Why you are protecting dates in `Model`?

Answer (score 13):

By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which provides an assortment of helpful methods, and extends the native PHP DateTime class.

Read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Just check your composer.json file for nesbot/carbon package. In case if you don't have you can install it by typing

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Alternative Solution is,

You could use Carbon::parse() to create object on the fly.

```
Carbon::parse($p->created_at)->diffForHumans();
```

Answer (score 8):

The Laravel `diffForHumans()` functions as I have used in version 5.2, only works when you are using on `created_at` and `updated_at`, otherwise it will bring you the `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string` error. even though you have used the `created_at` and `updated_at`, just be sure that on your migrations, you haven't used:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at');
$table->timestamp('updated_at');
```

But you have used

```
$table->timestamps();
```

There is a difference according to laravel
But just incase for some reason you wanted to use the `diffForHumans()` function for a column that is neither `created_at` and `updated_at`, **For instance** `expired_at`, Use Carbon

*What I can say in summary is that:*

1. You first create a new folder may be called `Addon` in your laravel project folder *e.g test-laravel*
2. Then inside the folder, you create a new file called `Carbon.php`.
3. Inside the `Carbon.php` file, enter:

---

```
namespace Carbon;

class Carbon extends \DateTime{
    //
}
```

Then go to your controller *e.g `ProductController.php`* and add the Carbon namespace to the file:

---

```
namespace Addon;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use ...

class ProductController extends Controller{
   $expire_date_string = '2016-07-27 12:45:32';
   //  Parse date with carbon
   $carbonated_date = Carbon::parse($expire_date_string);
   //  Assuming today was 2016-07-27 12:45:32
   $diff_date = $carbonated_date->diffForHumans(Carbon::now());
   echo $diff_date; // prints "1 month after"
}
```

For more information about the Carbon Controllers, visit: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use Carbon for a column that is neither created_at and updated_at just add the new column like expired_at to your model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'expired_at'
];
```

And then you can use ->diffForHumans();

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 3):

If in blade view:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Carbon`, like this:

```
$date = new \Carbon($p->created_at)->diffForHumans();
```

Comment: By default, `Eloquent` converts date properties in `$dates` to `Carbon` so it should work by using `$p->created_at->diffForHumans()`, since `created_at` is avaiable in `$dates` property and these suppose to be `Carbon` instaances.

Answer (score 1):

You con't need carbon.
In Laravel 8, add this line to your controller:

```
protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
```

Then you can use this in your blade :

```
{{ $project->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this in View File:**

```
$p->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

and

1. Confirm that `created_at` field must not empty
2. if Empty use a condition like `if (condition)`
3. don't need to use `protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];` in Model file