# FatalErrorException Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

How to fix this FatalErrorException Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string in Laravel 5.4?

It's showing an error when I use the function "diffForHumans()".

Overall, everything is okay without this.

**Controller code**:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Auth;
  use DB;
  Use App\Model\Books;
  use App\Model\ClassLevel;

 class BookController extends Controller{
 public function showBooks()
 {
    $books = DB::table('books as b')
        ->join('classes as c', 'b.class_ref_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->join('users as u', 'b.created_by', '=', 'u.id')
        ->select('u.fullname', 'c.engclassname', 'b.book_name','b.created_at','b.updated_at','b.id')
        ->get();
    return view('admin.book.view-book',compact('books'));
}
```

**View Page Code**:

```
@foreach($books as $d)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$d->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$d->created_at` isn't an object. Edit: is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278455/

Comment: @Scuzzy this function work for other page. if i echo this then its working . when i tried to echo with diffForHumans() function then its generate this error.

Comment: That error is very specifically saying that `$d->created_at` isn't an object that you can call the `diffForHumans` method against. Thus your data must be different to "the other pages"

Comment: Fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

I assume created_at would be date, buts its a string ("stringOfCharacters"... unless you've made into an object :) to debug try:

var_dump($d) - this should show if its object or array.
you access array using $d['created_at]
if its object using $d->created_at

or for your created_at field

you can as well try to cast object to array so...

$arrayOfObj = (array) $d;

var_dump($d['created_at'])

if its not an object, but a string then (more or less) obviously it wont work since string doesn't have methods/functions :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning to the View is an generic collection, and in order to use that, it needs to be the representation of an ORM. (A collection of ORM's for that matter)

```
return Books::join('classes', 'books.class_ref_id', 'classes.id')
        ->join('users', 'books.created_by','users.id')
        ->select('users.fullname', 'classes.engclassname', 'books.book_name','books.created_at','books.updated_at','books.id')
        ->get();
```

This will output a collection of Book with the information you require.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is PHP version issue.
You can change your code

```
{{$d->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
```

to

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->diffForHumans()
```

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but when you use `DB::table() ... ->get()`, you get a `Collection`, or single instance of a, `stdClass` object(s), and `created_at` is a String:

```php
$createdAt = DB::table('books')->first()->created_at;

dd($createdAt);

"2023-01-08 12:33:01"
```

By comparison, when you use a `Book.php` Model, you get a `Collection`, or single instance of a, `Book` object(s). By default, Models convert `created_at` and `updated_at` to `Carbon` instances:

```php
$createdAt = Book::first()->created_at;

dd($createdAt);

Illuminate\Support\Carbon {
  date: 2023-01-08 12:33:01.0 America/Toronto (-05:00),
}
```

Because of this, you can then do `$book->created_at->diffForHumans()` **only when using `Books::` and not `DB::table('books')`.**

If you want to use this functionality with `DB::table()`, then you need to convert it to a `Carbon` instance first:

```php
@foreach($books as $book)
  {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($book->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
@endforeach
```

So, TL;DR; Models convert some `created_at` and `updated_at` to `Carbon` instances, but `DB::table()` does not; as long as you're aware of this, you should be able to handle properly on the front end.